# Overriding hashCode() method does not allow saving of class properties in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to persist the following class in a Neo4J database using spring-data-neo4j version 4.0.0.RELEASE. It is a class named 'GroupCategory' with some fields like name, ownerId etc. It has overwritten the equals and hashcode methods as provided by eclipse framework.

```
@NodeEntity(label="GroupCategory")
public class GroupCategory implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Property private String uuid;
    @Property private String name;
    @Property private String creatorUuid;
    @Property private String ownerUuid;
    @Property private String profile;
    @Property private String status;

    @Relationship(type = GroupRelationshipNames.BELONGS_TO, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<GroupCategoryRelation> groupCategoryRelations = new ArrayList<GroupCategoryRelation>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCreatorUuid() {
        return creatorUuid;
    }

    public void setCreatorUuid(String creatorUuid) {
        this.creatorUuid = creatorUuid;
    }

    public String getOwnerUuid() {
        return ownerUuid;
    }

    public void setOwnerUuid(String ownerUuid) {
        this.ownerUuid = ownerUuid;
    }

    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<GroupCategoryRelation> getGroupCategoryRelations() {
        return groupCategoryRelations;
    }

    public void setGroupCategoryRelations(
            List<GroupCategoryRelation> groupCategoryRelations) {
        this.groupCategoryRelations = groupCategoryRelations;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GroupCategory [id=" + id + ", uuid=" + uuid + ", name=" + name
                + ", creatorUuid=" + creatorUuid + ", ownerUuid=" + ownerUuid
                + ", profile=" + profile + ", status=" + status
                + ", groupCategoryRelations=" + groupCategoryRelations + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((creatorUuid == null) ? 0 : creatorUuid.hashCode());
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((groupCategoryRelations == null) ? 0
                        : groupCategoryRelations.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((ownerUuid == null) ? 0 : ownerUuid.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((profile == null) ? 0 : profile.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((status == null) ? 0 : status.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((uuid == null) ? 0 : uuid.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        GroupCategory other = (GroupCategory) obj;
        if (creatorUuid == null) {
            if (other.creatorUuid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!creatorUuid.equals(other.creatorUuid))
            return false;
        if (groupCategoryRelations == null) {
            if (other.groupCategoryRelations != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!groupCategoryRelations.equals(other.groupCategoryRelations))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (ownerUuid == null) {
            if (other.ownerUuid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ownerUuid.equals(other.ownerUuid))
            return false;
        if (profile == null) {
            if (other.profile != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!profile.equals(other.profile))
            return false;
        if (status == null) {
            if (other.status != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!status.equals(other.status))
            return false;
        if (uuid == null) {
            if (other.uuid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!uuid.equals(other.uuid))
            return false;
        return true;
    }



}
```

I have a test case which first saves and later updates some properties of the objects like below. The test case is as follows

```
@Test
public void changeCategoryName(){
    String ownerUuid = "PERSON_0_UUID";
    String name = "GROUP_0";
    String name1 = "GROUP_1";

    GroupCategory groupCategory = new GroupCategory();
    groupCategory.setName(name);
    groupCategory.setOwnerUuid(ownerUuid);
    groupCategory.setProfile(Profile.PRIVATE.name());
    GroupCategory savedGroupCategory = groupCategoryService.create(groupCategory);

    System.out.println("----------- "+groupCategoryService.findByUuid(savedGroupCategory.getUuid()));
    Assert.assertTrue(groupCategoryService.findByUuid(savedGroupCategory.getUuid()).getName().equals(name));

    savedGroupCategory.setName(name1);
    savedGroupCategory = groupCategoryService.save(savedGroupCategory);
    System.out.println("----------- "+groupCategoryService.findByUuid(savedGroupCategory.getUuid()));
    Assert.assertTrue(groupCategoryService.findByUuid(savedGroupCategory.getUuid()).getName().equals(name1));


    savedGroupCategory.setName(name);
    groupCategoryService.save(savedGroupCategory);
    System.out.println("----------- "+groupCategoryService.findByUuid(savedGroupCategory.getUuid()));
    Assert.assertTrue(groupCategoryService.findByUuid(savedGroupCategory.getUuid()).getName().equals(name));


}
```

The answer of the three 'printlns' are given below

```
----------- GroupCategory [id=889, uuid=9f891006-3d89-4665-ae2f-4946d13b74ac, name=GROUP_0, creatorUuid=null, ownerUuid=PERSON_0_UUID, profile=PRIVATE, status=ACTIVE, groupCategoryRelations=[]]
----------- GroupCategory [id=889, uuid=9f891006-3d89-4665-ae2f-4946d13b74ac, name=GROUP_1, creatorUuid=null, ownerUuid=PERSON_0_UUID, profile=PRIVATE, status=ACTIVE, groupCategoryRelations=[]]
----------- GroupCategory [id=889, uuid=9f891006-3d89-4665-ae2f-4946d13b74ac, name=GROUP_1, creatorUuid=null, ownerUuid=PERSON_0_UUID, profile=PRIVATE, status=ACTIVE, groupCategoryRelations=[]]
```

If the 'name' field is looked at, it canbe observed that the field is saved and updated for the first two cases. But in the third case, while resetting to the previous value of 'Group_0', the name field is not saved.
The last assertion in the test case fails because the saved object retains  the previous value of 'Group1'. The three printlns will give the idea.

It so happens, that the transition of the value of name field from Group_0 to Group_1 works but the one from Group_1 back to Group_0 does not. If the   value is changed to any other value other than Group_0 from Group_1, then the value gets updated. That is, the save is not working if the value is being changed alternatively

If I remove the hashCode() method from the GroupCategory class, then all seems to work well. Specifically only commenting the hash code for name field does the trick like

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((creatorUuid == null) ? 0 : creatorUuid.hashCode());
    result = prime
            * result
            + ((groupCategoryRelations == null) ? 0
                    : groupCategoryRelations.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    //result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((ownerUuid == null) ? 0 : ownerUuid.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((profile == null) ? 0 : profile.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((status == null) ? 0 : status.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((uuid == null) ? 0 : uuid.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

But the same problem persits for other fields as well. As for now it seems that, updating values alternatively (value1 to value2, then again to value1) does not seem to work if hashCode() is being overridden in the class

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed, please use version 1.1.6 of neo4j-ogm.

**Update**

SDN depends on the Neo4j OGM library. SDN 4.0 was released with an older version of Neo4j-OGM that does not contain this bug fix.
You can add this dependency to override the version of Neo4j OGM-

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.6</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: I am using the following dependency in pom.xml. {<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId> <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>} Do I need to switch to neo4j-ogm ? Will be great if you can comment on which one to use (spring-data-neo4j or neo4j-ogm) and why so.